# prove the convergence of the following sequence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given that $a>0$ and
$x_{n+1} = \displaystyle{\frac{x_nx_{n-1}+a}{x_n+x_{n-1}}}$.

Prove that if $ x_1+x_0 >0$, then $x_n + x_{n-1} >0$ for all positive integer $n$ and $x_n$ converges to $\sqrt{a}$

Graphically I can see that the statement is true, but I don't know how to prove it rigourously, I tried M.I., moving the terms around, but I still can't even get a single meaningful thing to proceed. Is there any trick here?

(edit: I changed the $x_{n+1}$ in the denominator to $x_{n-1}$)

Comment: Are you sure it is $x_n+x_{n+1}$ in the denominator for the definition of $x_{n+1}$

Comment: I'm pretty sure you meant $x_{n+2} $ not $x_{n+1} $.  It's positive by strong induction.  If $x_n $ and $x_{n-1}$ are positive then $x_{n+1}$ is positive.

Comment: yes, you are right, I'm so sorry that I made that typo. The $x_{n+1}$ in the denominator should be $x_{n-1}$.

Comment: *Only a hint*: You can use $\sqrt{x_n x_{n-1}}\leq \frac{x_n + x_{n-1}}{2}$ and perhaps it's also useful to know that $x+\frac{1}{x}$ has a minimum at $x=1$.